# android RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to run a function in the background and while the function is performing I have to show a progress dialog.
this is how I call the function

```
.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.str_accept)) { _, _ ->
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                        pdfReportRequest()
                    }
```

and this is how I perform Coroutine task

```
private suspend fun pdfReportRequest() {
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog?
        progressDialogBuilder.setView(progressBinding.root)
                .setTitle(context?.getString(R.string.exporting_as_pdf_file))
                .show()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            getResultFromApi()
        }
        alertDialog = progressDialogBuilder.create()
        alertDialog.dismiss()
    }
```

but it gives me this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: I have tried to use this `val handler = Handler()
            handler.post {
                // Do stuff...
                progressDialogBuilder.setView(progressBinding.root)
                        .setTitle(context?.getString(R.string.exporting_as_pdf_file))
                        .show()
            }` but it does work

Comment: U should using `Dispatchers.Main` instead of `Dispatchers.Default` to show Alert dialog .

Comment: But it gives me another error here ` progressDialogBuilder.setView(progressBinding.root)
                        .setTitle(context?.getString(R.string.exporting_as_pdf_file))
                        .show() //here`  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

Comment: This is something else . Probably because you are using same builder again and again i.e . Create a new every time .

Comment: Ok thank you I got it.